# Full API URL in Swagger editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-editor

I have a valid Json file for online Swagger editor. How can I set complete url for API to test like https://mywebsite/api/apiMethod

What currently I am getting is: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Swagger JSON specification file may contain hostname part of URL of your service - see https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swaggerHost (then "Try this operation" feature of editor will use it).

Also you may use swagger-ui to try to use it with specific test website URL, see example at http://petstore.swagger.io/